# Position of two regression equations ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have 3 variables. x = age, y = spending_score and gender (female/male). I want to see the relationship b/w y and x for each gender. I have a scatter plot with two regression lines one for females and one for males: formula = y ~ x, method = "lm". I want to put the two regression equations on the plot, but the equations in their default position (topleft) are hardly readable. So i need to change the position of the two regression equations to the top right area. But when i try the two equations are on top of each other, so they are again hardly readable. Please help! Thank you!

```
x <- df$age
y <- df$spending_score


formula <- y ~ x


k <- ggplot(df, aes(age, spending_score, color = gender)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Spending score", title = "Spending score vs. age") +
  stat_smooth(aes(fill = gender, color = gender), method = "lm", formula = formula) +
  stat_regline_equation(
    label.x = 50, label.y = 80,
    aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
    formula = formula
    ) +
  theme_classic2() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
ggpar(k, palette = "jco")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only provide 1 value for label.x and label.y, so all the text takes that position. If you have two or more lines, you need to provide a vector that is as long

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
F = as.formula("y~x")
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
geom_point() +
stat_smooth(aes(fill = Species, color = Species), method = "lm", formula = F) +
stat_regline_equation(
          label.x = c(6,6,6), label.y = c(4,4.25,4.5),
          aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
          formula=F,size=3
)
```

To elaborate a bit more, in this dataset, Species in iris has 3 levels, setosa,versicolor,virginica. When I specify label.x and label.y, the first value is for setosa, i.e x=6,y=4 and for versicolor, x=6,y=4.25 and so on.

[image]

Comment: glad it helped you. I still make stupid mistakes from time to time :)

Comment: Is there a neat programmatic way to specify sensible numbers for the `label.y` vector?

Comment: @MarkNeal, in this case, max(iris$Sepal.Width)  + seq(0,length.out=3,by=diff(range(iris$Sepal.Width))/10) or something along this line?

Comment: I've raised a github issue at [ggpubr](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/247) that deals with a related location issue for multiple stats results on a graph.